# How to inset a hidden value into another column of table using html form

Tags: html

```html
 <select name="plan" class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Please select your plan</option>
      <option value="10" value="free">  Free</option>
      <option>Standard</option>
      <option >Premimium</option>
      <option >Professional</option>
   
    </select>
```

I want to insert value="free" with value="10" to another column of same table

Comment: What table?  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: i have a table in which column are plan and money and i want to inert 10 in money column hiddenly

Comment: So you're just looking for an `<input type="hidden" ...>` element?

Comment: i want <option name="money" value="10" >Free</option>
where free should be inesrted in plan and 10 in money column of table

Comment: `<option>` elements don't have a`name` attribute.  The `<select>` element has the `name`.  If you want a separate form value to be posted, then you'll need a separate form element.

Comment: But i want in same and value 10 should be posted hidden

Comment: Yes, posting a *hidden value* is what a *hidden input* is for.  Something like: `<input type="hidden" name="money" value="10" />`  Note of course that users *can* edit this value before posting the form, it shouldn't be implicitly trusted just like any other client-submitted value.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
 <select name="plan" id='something' class="form-control selectpicker" >
      <option value=" " >Please select your plan</option>
     <option value="10" data-value="free">  Free</option>
     <option>Standard</option>
      <option >Premimium</option>
       <option >Professional</option>

    </select>
```

Then you can access it using jQuery:

```
 $('#something').attr('data-value');
```

Comment: and how will data be insert separately into two columns

Comment: where is table ? what do you mean by table ? is there any single word "table" in your code ?

Comment: my mistake i should have told you this answer in the comment but seriously learn how to ask a question.. read stackoverflow's guide...

Comment: i want add 10 hidden with free into databse